# Parallelizing a nested for loop: parcelling out data

Tags: c++, c, openmp, nested-loops

I have two functions with integer arguments; call them *f* and *g*. I also have another function *h* taking two integer arguments. Given a square U of size D (meaning: {m0,m0+1,..,m0+D-1}x{n0,n0+1,...,n0+D-1}), I have a procedure for computing the sum of f(n) g(m) h(n,m) in time roughly linear on D, given arrays `farr`, `garr` containing f(m0),f(m0+1),...,f(m0+D-1) and g(n0),g(n0+1),...,g(n0+D-1); let us treat that procedure as a black box, which we invoke by means of the call Sum(farr,garr,m0,n0,D), say. We can compute farr[0]=f(m0),...farr[D-1]=f(m0+D-1) or garr[0]=garr(n0),garr[1]=g(n0+1),...,garr[n0+D-1] in time roughly linear on D, by means of the calls Fillf(f,m0,D) and Fillg(g,m0,D).

The question is how to compute efficiently the sum of f(n) g(m) h(n,m) for all (n,m) in {0,1,...,rD-1}x{0,1,...,rD-1} (say) in parallel.  That's easy in the abstract - what I would like to know is how to do it in OpenMP.

The simplest approach might be something like this:

```
S=0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) private(m0,n0,farr,garr) reduction(+:S)
for(m0=0; m0<r*D; m0+=D)
 for(n0=0; n0<r*D; n0+=D)
  farr = (short *) calloc(D,sizeof(int));
  Fillf(farr,m0,D);
  garr = (short *) calloc(D,sizeof(int));
  Fillg(garr,n0,D);
  S+=Sum(farr,garr,m0,n0,D)
  free(garr);
  free(farr);
```

That works well enough, but it has the disadvantage that each segment of `farr` and `garr` gets computed r times instead of once. Hardly a tragedy, given that the overall computational complexity is not changed (it is not going to be better than O(r^2 D)), but nevertheless undesirable.

Another approach is to write

```
S=0;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) private(m0,n0,farr,garr) reduction(+:S)
for(m0=0; m0<r*D; m0+=D) {
 farr = (short *) calloc(D,sizeof(int));
 Fillf(farr,m0,D);
 for(n0=0; n0<r*D; n0+=D) {
  garr = (short *) calloc(D,sizeof(int));
  Fillg(garr,n0,D);
  S+=Sum(farr,garr,m0,n0,D)
  free(garr);
 }
 free(farr);
}
```

This is also a working solution, but: (a) each segment of `garr` still gets computed r times rather than once, (b) parallelization will be inefficient if the number of available threads is considerably greater than `r` (but smaller than `r^2`). Here we cannot use `collapse(2)`, since there are things going on between the two loops.

It should clearly be possible to do better. What would be a straightforward way to code the more or less obvious procedure using OpenMP? (Should one precompute segments of `farr` and `garr` of size about sqrt(s) D, where s is the number of available threads, and then do a nested loop with `collapse(2)` for `m0` and `n0` going over segments of length about D sqrt(s)?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid duplicative computation of both `farr` and `garr`, then you have at least two options:

1. Compute and store all all the `garr` in advance, in a separate loop, and take an approach otherwise the same as your second alternative.  Optionally, compute and store all the `farr` in advance, too.
2. Modify your second alternative to parallelize the inner loop instead of the outer loop.  This will also enable you to hoist the allocation and deallocation of `farr` out of the loop:

   ```
   S = 0;
   farr = malloc(D, sizeof(int));
   for (int m0 = 0; m0 < r * D; m0 += D) {
       int S2 = 0;
       Fillf(farr, m0, D);
       #pragma omp parallel for private(farr, m0) reduction(+:S2)
       for (int n0 = 0; n0 < r * D; n0 += D) {
           int *garr = calloc(D, sizeof(int));
           Fillg(garr, n0, D);
           S2 += Sum(farr, garr, m0, n0, D)
           free(garr);
       }
       S += S2;
   }
   free(farr);
   ```

Note also,

- If `Fillf()` assumes that its array argument is initially zero-filled (as `calloc()` ensures), then hoisting the memory allocation out of the loop will require manually zero-filling in advance of each call, but that's still likely to be cheaper than deallocation and reallocation.
- I removed the scheduling clause, because it doesn't appear that dynamic scheduling would be of any advantage to this computation
- Declaring `farr` private makes only the pointer private, not the data to which it points.  Moreover, since neither `farr` nor `m0` is modified inside the parallel loop, it doesn't actually serve a useful purpose to declare them private.  I left the `private` clause in the example code primarily as a focus for these remarks.
- The savings on recomputing the various values of `garr` stands against additional overhead from finer-grained parallelism.  This is more likely to be a win if the work of each iteration of the inner loop is still relatively large.

Comment: Thanks. 1. is not really an option as such, since the space complexity can shoot up. Wouldn't it make more sense to compute f and g in chunks of size sqrt(s) D, where s is the number of threads? Also, why would the second alternative be preferrable to the first alternative?

Comment: I actually tried your option 2. first. The problem there is again (it seems to me) that r may be substantially smaller than the number of threads. (Assume r^2 is at least as large as the number of threads, so that we have a hope of using resources efficiently.)  In fact, of the options listed above, the one that runs fastest for my particular application is the first one ("simplest approach") even though it computes each value of f and g many times over.

Comment: And I take that declaring int n0, int *garr in the innermost loop has the same effect as making them private?

Comment: Lastly - could dynamic scheduling help if computing the sum of f(n) g(m) h(n,m) takes considerably more time in some squares than in others? Of course then any attempt at making the procedure more efficient by splitting into parts of side sqrt(s) D is compromised, so we might as well assume that that's not the case.

Comment: @HAHelfgott, yes, precomputing all the data may place heavier requirements on storage than you want to incur.  This is a time *vs*. space tradeoff.  But if you parallelize the outer loop, with or without `collapse(2)`, and use more than one thread to execute it, then I see no other way to avoid duplicate computation of `garr`.  And that was the question, after all.  It is not out of the question that such duplication nevertheless produces faster code.

Comment: Variables declared inside a parallel region are private with respect to the innermost containing parallel region and, therefore, all parallel regions within which that one is nested.  Additionally, the iteration variable of a `parallel for` is also automatically private.

Comment: And yes, dynamic scheduling would help if there were significant, systematic variation or large random variation in the running time of `Sum()`.  But your description gives me no reason to think that that would be the case.

Comment: Yes, I do not see how one can avoid some duplication without increasing storage to something in the order of r D. And yes, *some* duplication is something we should be able to live with; indeed, as I said, in what I am doing, the first alternative, which is the most wasteful, runs the fastest, among the ones I have tried.

Comment: The (non-implemented) possibility I sketched at the end was meant to reduce duplication and improve parallelisation while holding storage as low as one reasonably can (namely, O(sqrt(s) D)). There are really *three* things among which there can be tradeoffs here: space, total computing time, and efficiency of parallelisation.

Comment: You may split the combined `parallel for` directive and allocate and deallocate `garr` outside the for loop.

Comment: _"Moreover, since neither `farr` nor `m0` is modified inside the parallel loop, it doesn't actually serve a useful purpose to declare them private"_ This isn't necessarily true for most widespread OpenMP implementations. OpenMP regions usually get outlined in separate functions and private variables simply become local variables in the outlined code while shared variables are stored in special structures passed by and accessed via (double) pointer indirection. Making often-used read-only shared variables `firstprivate` (note `first-`) could bring measurable performance benefits.

Comment: @Hristoiliev Yes, that was a possibility we discuss (and it was in fact the first, and slowest, option I tried).

Comment: @HAHelfgott I mean outside the inner for loop but still inside the parallel region. Right now you are allocating and deallocating `garr` on each iteration. (actually, I'm not sure to which of my comments you've replied)